# session of Student in Database?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, erd

How to Save The Data into Table of the following condition in the Student Management System.
1: Student table has its personal Information in Student Table 
2: Student Study in Class (Class table has its own Information) One Student Has one Class
3: Session table Session Year Such Like (2020-2021)
4: Student Result table Table (Result of Table)

My question is that, if we enter the Student Information, Class Information, Session, and Result if Student Pass in 2020 Session, How to keep the Record of session and progress of a student each year. or do I need to enter again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your session table should have multiple entries for each of the Sessional Year with primary key as session Id.

Result table should have studentStudyId and sessionid and they form composite primary Key.By that way you can store results for all sessional years for each student.

Datamodel for the objects provided are below,Primary Key for each column can be auto incremented.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]